# Proof $ \lim \arctan (X_n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hypothetically , if $ \lim X_n=L$.

How can I prove that  $ \lim \arctan (X_n)= \arctan (L) $ ?

Comment: Fixing the typos would be welcome. Use continuity.

Comment: It comes down to the continuity of $\arctan$ - try arguing based on this.